# SMB Exception 'The parameter is incorrect' when connecting with jcifs to Samba 4

Tags: java, samba, jcifs

I used jcifs to connect to a samba drive for a long time. Since the samba server got updated and uses Samba 4 now, it fails to connect with the error message `The parameter is incorrect`. The network directory is still accessible through other boxes via smb. It looks like a problem with jcifs and a change in the protocol with Samba 4. Does anybody know what could be the problem?

```
Stack Trace: jcifs.smb.SmbException: The parameter is incorrect.
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.checkStatus(SmbTransport.java:545)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:645)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:244)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.send(SmbTree.java:119)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.send(SmbFile.java:770)
```

I tested jcifs version 1.3.14 and 1.3.17

Comment: Which version of jcifs are you using?

Comment: I tried with 1.3.14 and 1.3.17

Comment: Since you said it had been connecting for a long time, I thought an old version could be the reason, but if you already tested with 1.3.17, I got nothin', sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when copying a big file of more than 4gb to a network drive with FAT as File system. Fat only support up to 4GB for a file.